# Using NSPredicate get only values of a particular key from an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I do not know the values. I only know the key.

```
arrTripCat : 
(
    { tripcategory = "general_tourism"; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; },
    { tripcategory = "art_museums"; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; },
    { tripcategory = architecture; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; }
);
```

The `NSPredicate` I tried :

```
NSArray *arrTripCat = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.dictSearchResult objectForKey:@"TripCategories"]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.@allKeys contains[cd] %@",@"tripcategory"];

NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[filteredArray addObjectsFromArray:[arrTripCat filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

after this, the `filteredArray` still has all of the data in the same format as before.

```
filteredArray:
(
    { tripcategory = "general_tourism"; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; },
    { tripcategory = "art_museums"; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; },
    { tripcategory = architecture; },
    { tripcategory = nightlife; }
);
```

The end result I'm looking to get is to have all of the values for the `tripcategory` key put into an array. i.e.

```
 ( general_tourism, nightlife, art_museums, architecture )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a predicate because you aren't actually filtering, all you need is:

```
NSArray *tripCategories = [arrTripCat valueForKey:@"tripcategory"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to filter, you want to fold the results, so using a predicate doesn't serve your purpose. In plain Cocoa, you can do:

```
NSMutableArray *results = @[].mutableCopy;
for (NSDictionary *dict in arrTripCat) {
   [results addObject:dict[@"tripcategory"];
}
```

This will give you ( general_tourism, nightlife, art_museums, architecture ).