# NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject issue

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to get `Title` data from the server but unfortunately I'm getting nothing as it is shown in the `NSLog` below. Shouldn't I get the `Title` dictionary? Please where would be my issue?

While I want to set that data in the UITableVeiw

```
- (void)getNews{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.ashx"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         NSDictionary *getData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];

         if([[[getData objectForKey:@"Success"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

             [dataNewsArray addObjectsFromArray:[[greeting objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Datasource"]];
         }

         NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dataHaberlerArray forKey:@"Title"];

         NSLog(@"Check %@", aDict);
       }
   }];
}
```

NSLog result as like this;

```
Check {
Title =     (
            {
        Content = "";
        Date = "13.10.2014";
        Time = "01:17:34";
        Title = "example";
    },
```

NSLog for dataNewsArray

```
2014-10-13 13:40:14.828 new_8[8742:346345] Check (
    {
    Content = " ";
    Date = "13.10.2014";
    Time = "01:38:53";
    Title = "*test*";
},
```

Comment: How you are trying to get the title data

Comment: hey @CAN please put your tableview cell code.

Comment: put the log for 'dataHaberlerArray'

Comment: @RameshMuthe I'm trying to get it from the dataNewsArray from the server.

Comment: Yes, I am asking to print the log for 'dataNewsArray'

Comment: Are you looking for? : [dataHaberlerArray[0] objectForKey:@"Title"];

Comment: What you have is correct for the code you have entered.  You are creating a dictionary that contains a key 'title' and a value which is an array (dataHaberlerArray).  This array appears to be an array of dictionaries

Comment: @BaSha Your code is working right

Comment: @BaSha I'm getting only one value how to get the rest while there is 10 titles.

Comment: For some time change this line '
         NSDictionary *aDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dataHaberlerArray forKey:@"Title123"];'

Comment: @RameshMuthe this method is working fine but I'm just printing the same value while there is 10 different titles [dataNewsArray[0] objectForKey:@"Title"];

Comment: With using my line print the complete 'dataNewsArray'data

Comment: 2014-10-13 13:56:13.201 new_8[9012:354569] Check {
    Title123 =     (
                {
            Content = ""
            Date = "13.10.2014";
            Time = "01:52:14";
            Title = "****"; @RameshMuthe This is the result with your line

Comment: Please once change the Title key to some other key, here in your response there are two Title same keys it is the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62969/discussion-between-can-and-ramesh-muthe).

Comment: You're totally hosed because you don't understand what you're doing -- how JSON works and how NSArrays and NSDictionarys work.  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax, then study NSDictionary and NSArray specs.

Comment: You give us no clue as to what `dataHaberlerArray` is or what's in it.

Comment: @HotLicks  I'm sorry at that time I was trying to put different name which is the same as dataNewsArray. Sorry!!

Comment: `dataNewsArray` is an array (as can be seen by the leading `(`).  It has multiple NSDictionary elements in it.  If you want the data from it you need to iterate through it (or use, eg, `valueForKey` that iterates for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the below code to get one title

```
[[[aDict objectForKey:@"Title"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Title"]];
```

for all the titles use the below code

```
  NSMutableArray *titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[[aDict objectForKey:@"Title"] count]; i++) {

        [titleArray addObject:[[[aDict objectForKey:@"Title"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    }
```

The above solution provide the answer, but there is some other way using predicate to get the data

Comment: It is working fine but why I'm getting only one title? There are 10 titles.

Comment: If you need to get all the dictinary key at a time then we can use in this way

Comment: There is no Title123 in the OP's JSON.  And there's no need to rename one of the Title instances to Title123.

Comment: And there's no obvious need to insert the "Title" value into a single-element dictionary.  That accomplishes nothing other than to further obfuscate.

Comment: Once check this post 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009305/using-nspredicate-get-only-values-of-a-particular-key-from-an-array-of-dictionar'